# Mac Yosemite Spotlight - force it to index specific Library folders?

Tags: spotlight, osx-yosemite

How can I get Spotlight to index a directory in the system>Library folder?

I'm trying to get Spotlight running 10.10.3 to index some folders in the Macintosh HD/Library folder. I'm not getting any search results from these folders so it appears Spotlight is not searching/indexing them. The folder can be found at:

Macintosh HD/Library/FileMaker Server/HTTPServer/htdocs/

I am getting search results for other Library folders, such as my web root folder at:

/Library/WebServer/Documents/

Is there a way to force Spotlight to also index the Library/FileMaker Server/HTTPServer/htdocs folder as well?

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to turn off Spotlight on a FileMaker Server. See page 182: https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/13/en/fms13_help.pdf

Comment: Thanks - should have mentioned I'm aware of that - I want to index FileMaker Server's web root folder that I referenced above. I will not be indexing the FileMaker Server database folders as I have excluded those from Spotlight.